# How do we password protect this one page with the codes in CSV file?

Tags: php, apache

How do password protect this one page (on the website developed in PHP) with the codes in CSV file? Any of these codes should allow user access to the page. There is no username. Just password which would be random/unique numbers.

How this can be done by server (apache)/htaccess settings.

Thanks!

Comment: The CSV passwords file is mostly constant or will keep changing?
You might write a script that create a .htpasswd file based on the CSV file and run it overnight. (And them use it with AuthUserFile and HttpAuthLogin on .htaccess.)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the passwords in memory, so I would use this function to parse it into an array when the page loads: [PHP fgetcsv function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Then, when you have the values in an array, it's easy to traverse through the array and see if the user's password matches any password in the CSV file.

Hope this works for you.